# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect Holding Onto Image Data - Leaking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to take an image snapshot, crop it, and save it to a UIImageView.

I have tried this from a few dozen different directions but here is the general setup.

First, I am running this under ARC, XCODE 7.2, testing on a 6Plus phone iOS 9.2.

Here is now the delegate is setup..

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"CameraViewController : imagePickerController");


    //Get the Image Data
    NSData *getDataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 0.9);

    // Turn it into a UI image
    UIImage *getCapturedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:getDataImage];

    // Figure out the size and build the rectangle we are going to put the image into
    CGSize imageSize = getCapturedImage.size;
    CGFloat imageScale = getCapturedImage.scale;
    int yCoord = (imageSize.height - ((imageSize.width*2)/3))/2;
    CGRect getRect = CGRectMake(0, yCoord, imageSize.width, ((imageSize.width*2)/3));
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(getRect.origin.x*imageScale,
                             getRect.origin.y*imageScale,
                             getRect.size.width*imageScale,
                             getRect.size.height*imageScale);


    //Resize the image and store it
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([getCapturedImage CGImage], rect);

    //Stick the resulting image into an image variable
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    //Release that reference
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    //Save the newly cropped image to a UIImageView property
    _imageView.image = cropped;


    _saveBtn.hidden = NO;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // After we are finished with dismissing the picker, run the below to close out the camera tool
        [self dismissCameraViewFromImageSelect];

    }];


}
```

When I run the above I get the below image.

---

[image: First retain]

---

At this point I am viewing the image in the previously set _imageView.image.  And the image data has gobbled up 30MB.  But when I back out of this view, the image data is still retained.

If I try to go through the process of capturing a new image this is what I get.

---

[image: Second retain]

---

And when I bypass resizing the image and assign it to the ImageView there is no 30MB gobbled.

I have looked at all the advice on this and everything suggested doesn't make a dent but lets go over what I tried and didn't work.

---

Did not work.

1. Putting it in a @autoreleasepool block.

This never seems to work.  Maybe I am not doing it right but having tried this a few different ways, nothing released the memory.

2. `CGImageRelease(imageRef);`

I am doing that but I have tried this a number of different ways.  Still no luck.

3. `CFRelease(imageRef);`

Also doesn't work.

3. Setting `imageRef = nil;`

Still retains.  Even the combination of that and CGImageRelease didn't work for me.

I have tried separating the cropping aspect into its own function and returning the results but still no luck.

I haven't found anything particularly helpful online and all references to similar issues have advice (as mentioned above) that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: Try profiling for leaks in instruments, that could tell you exactly what's not getting released

Comment: I did that, which is where the pictures above come from.  I can of course narrow it down to the memory, and I can identify that it is an ImageIO, jpeg thing, which I figured out when it dropped the image down to the CGImage level for creating a framed image.

And as I stated, I know exactly where and what variables pass that information along to that place where it is locked down.  Using the methods recommended for releasing it hasn't worked yet.

If you know of a better method for researching that though I am all ears as I am dumbfounded as to how to get that memory released.

Comment: no, you're profiling for allocations in your screenshots. There's a specific tool in Instruments for leaks, that should pinpoint the source to a specific function that's creating the memory that isn't being released.

Comment: well I just ran the method 100 times and it didn't leak any memory. Although  I cut out a couple lines of code that weren't related to the image data (my method: https://infinit.io/_/udpDuhk). So the most likely explanation is that your code somehow is leaking elsewhere.

Comment: What if have UIImage *getCapturedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:getDataImage]; directly?

Comment: @originaluser2 Sorry, let me clarify.  Yes you are correct, in that instrument i am profiling for allocations.  I already used the leaks profiling tool and was able to narrow it down to exactly the above function and the line with "UIImageJPEGRepresentation" in it.  But when I run this without using "CGImageCreateWithImageInRect" it releases memory just fine.  But using "CGImageCreateWithImageInRect" retains memory indefinitely.

Comment: @Allen Thanks I will give that a try.  Not sure why it would make a difference but at this point, I will try anything.

Comment: @WadeCantley After reviewing it again. I noticed you set compression 0.9 for UIImageJPEGRepresentation. I'm wondering if it's necessary since the 0.9 is so high. As I know UIImageJPEGRepresentation will hold a second copy of a image. Maybe you could also try UIImage *getCapturedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; since it's a easy change see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Allen It was originally set to 1.0  by the original programmer but I changed that to see if it made any noticeable difference at least in the size. At 0.9 it didn't seem to touch it.  I will research the size compression a little more to see if I can conserve memory during the process and still maintain the size and quality we need. I will also apply your suggestions and see what comes up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after much time thinking on this, I decided to just start from scratch and since most of my recent work has been in Swift, I put together a swift class that can be called, controls the camera, and passes up the image through a delegate to the caller.

The end result is that I don't have this memory leak where some variable is holding on to the memory of the previous image and I can use it in my current project by bridging the Swift class file to my Obj-C ViewControllers.

Here is the Code for the class that does the fetching.

```
//
//  CameraOverlay.swift
//  CameraTesting
//
//  Created by Chris Cantley on 3/3/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Chris Cantley. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

//We want to pass an image up to the parent class once the image has been taken so the easiest way to send it up
// and trigger the placing of the image is through a delegate.
protocol CameraOverlayDelegate: class {
    func cameraOverlayImage(image:UIImage)
}

class CameraOverlay: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    //MARK: Internal Variables

    //Setting up the delegate reference to be used later on.
    internal var delegate: CameraOverlayDelegate?


    //Varibles for setting the camera view
    internal var returnImage : UIImage!
    internal var previewView : UIView!
    internal var boxView:UIView!
    internal let myButton: UIButton = UIButton()

    //Setting up Camera Capture required properties
    internal var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    internal var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
    internal let session=AVCaptureSession()
    internal var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput!

    //When we put up the camera preview and the button we have to reference a parent view so this will hold the
    // parent view passed into the class so that other methods can work with it.
    internal var view : UIView!



    //When this class is instantiated, we want to require that the calling class passes us
    //some view that we can tie the camera previewer and button to.

    //MARK: - Instantiation Methods
    init(parentView: UIView){


        //Instantiate the reference to the passed-in UIView
        self.view = parentView

        //We are doing the following here because this only needs to be setup once per instantiation.

        //Create the output container with settings to specify that we are getting a still Image, and that it is a JPEG.
        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        //Now we are sticking the image into the above formatted container
        session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    }

    //MARK: - Public Functions
    func showCameraView() {

        //This handles showing the camera previewer and button
        self.setupCameraView()

        //This sets up the parameters for the camera and begins the camera session.
        self.setupAVCapture()
    }

    //MARK: - Internal Functions

    //When the user clicks the button, this gets the image, sends it up to the delegate, and shuts down all the Camera related views.
    internal func didPressTakePhoto(sender: UIButton) {

        //Create a media connection...
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {

            //Setup the orientation to be locked to portrait
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

            //capture the still image from the camera
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {

                    //Get the image data
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                    //The 2.0 scale halves the scale of the image.  Where as the 1.0 gives you the full size.
                    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 2.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up)


                    // What size is this image.
                    let imageSize = image.size
                    let imageScale = image.scale
                    let yCoord = (imageSize.height - ((imageSize.width*2)/3))/2
                    let getRect = CGRectMake(0, yCoord, imageSize.width, ((imageSize.width*2)/3))
                    let rect = CGRectMake(getRect.origin.x*imageScale, getRect.origin.y*imageScale, getRect.size.width*imageScale, getRect.size.height*imageScale)
                    let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect)
                    //let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

                    //This app forces the user to use landscapto take pictures so this simply turns the image so that it looks correct when we take the image.
                    let newImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: image.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Down)

                    //Pass the image up to the delegate.
                    self.delegate?.cameraOverlayImage(newImage)

                    //stop the session
                    self.session.stopRunning()

                    //Remove the views.
                    self.previewView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.myButton.removeFromSuperview()

                    //By this point the image has been handed off to the caller through the delegate and memory has been cleaned up.

                }
            })
        }
    }


    internal func setupCameraView(){

        //Add a view that is big as the frame that acts as a background.
        self.boxView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.addSubview(self.boxView)

        //Add Camera Preview View
        // This sets up the previewView to be a 3:2 aspect ratio
        let newHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2 * 3
        self.previewView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, newHeight))
        self.previewView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()


        self.previewView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        self.view.addSubview(previewView)


        //Add the button.
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,40)
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        myButton.setTitle("press me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        myButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y:(self.view.frame.height - myButton.frame.height ) )
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: "didPressTakePhoto:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)

    }


    internal func setupAVCapture(){

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices();

        // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
        for device in devices {

            // Make sure this particular device supports video
            if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {

                // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the front camera
                if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                    captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                    if captureDevice != nil {

                        //-> Now that we have the back of the camera, start a session.
                        beginSession()
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Sets up the session
    internal func beginSession(){

        var err : NSError? = nil
        var deviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput?

        //See if we can get input from the Capture device as defined in setupAVCapture()
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            deviceInput = nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            print("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        }

        //If we can add input into the AVCaptureSession() then do so.
        if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
            self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
        }


        //Now show layers that were setup in the previewView, and mask it to the boundary of the previewView layer.
        let rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer
        rootLayer.masksToBounds=true


        //put a live video capture based on the current session.
        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session);

        // Determine how to fill the previewLayer.  In this case, I want to fill out the space of the previewLayer.
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds


        //Put the sublayer into the previewLayer
        rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)

        session.startRunning()

    }


}
```

Here is how I am using this class in a view controller.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CameraTesting
//
//  Created by Chris Cantley on 2/26/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Chris Cantley. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, CameraOverlayDelegate{

    //Setting up the class reference.
    var cameraOverlay : CameraOverlay!

    //Connected to the UIViewController main view.
    @IBOutlet var getView: UIView!

    //Connected to an ImageView that will display the image when it is passed back to the delegate.
    @IBOutlet weak var imgShowImage: UIImageView!


    //Connected to the button that is pressed to bring up the camera view.
    @IBAction func btnPictureTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

        //Remove the image from the UIImageView and take another picture.
        self.imgShowImage.image = nil
        self.cameraOverlay.showCameraView()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Pass in the target UIView which in this case is the main view
        self.cameraOverlay = CameraOverlay(parentView: getView)

        //Make this class the delegate for the instantiated class.  
        //That way it knows to receive the image when the user takes a picture
        self.cameraOverlay.delegate = self


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        //Nothing here but if you run out of memorry you might want to do something here.

    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
            UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
            UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
                return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //This references the delegate from CameraOveralDelegate
    func cameraOverlayImage(image: UIImage) {

        //Put the image passed up from the CameraOverlay class into the UIImageView
        self.imgShowImage.image = image
    }



}
```

Here is a link to the project where I put that together.
[GitHub - Boiler plate get image from camera](https://github.com/CWadeCantley/Barebones-Camera-Capture)